# application load balancer fails to upload large file

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-alb

I have a bit of a problem. 
I have a php larvel application that sits on a ec2 linux instance behind an application load balancer.

When I try to upload a large file the process fails  with no error no where. 
I have set the idle timeout to 2000 - thats no it.

I have switched on the same server to a classic load balancer and it works with no problem.

I a very sorry that I have no additional data to provide, but maybe someone knows why would a ALB fail a large post request?

Comment: How long does it take before it fails? How large is the file? What are your webserver's max post size and max upload size settings?

Comment: I have found the problem. 
It fails because of http/2.

Comment: Please post a detailed answer to your question, so others can learn from it :)

Comment: I find it difficult to believe that *"no error"* can be found in the ALB log or the web server log or the application log or the browser's developer console.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot I get it.
The thins is, I debuged it. There was no error. 
It got to the function but didn't pass the data it should, and as there are IF checking the request, the function just ended. The programmer didn't handle an option of an empty request. So it looks like everything was just fine.

Answer (score 0):

For the benefit of future seekers 
The problem was that **http/2** was on in application load balancer.
The application didn't know to parse the data correctly and was passing trough an empty response.
The function was written so so, and only checked if it has some value in the array - it looked like it was ended successfully.